# Yum cache issue?

Tags: centos, yum

So I recently tried to run yum update and yum install perl.
For some reason this error popped up:

```
-bash-4.1# yum install libpcap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Error: Error making cache directory: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/epel error was: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/epel'
```

I have tried yum clean all but that error still shows. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On my system the /var/cache/yum was a link to another directory which didn't exist - recreated the link and everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your cachedir is a writable directory by entering

```
ls -ld /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/epel
```

It should print sthg like

```
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4096 Aug  4 23:27 /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/epel
```

You can then check yum config and log files and if there is nothing suspicious, post your yum version.

```
grep -i error  /var/log/yum.log
cat /etc/yum.conf
yum --version
```